# Testing Off-Hours in PowerShell

Tags: date, datetime, powershell-3.0

I need a way to test Off-Hours in PowerShell. My Off-Hours are 7pm-7am. I’m not interested in the date part. The test is only for the time. I tried a few options but no access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easier to use the complete timestamp.

```bsh
$now   = Get-Date
$start = $now.Date.AddHours(7)
$end   = $now.Date.AddHours(19)

if ($start -le $now -and $end -ge $now) {
  'within work hours'
} else {
  'outside work hours'
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ansgar Wiechers! Very neat.

Comment: @RaviLobo Is there a particular reason why you unaccepted the answer 9 months after accepting it?

Answer (score 1):

A bit of googling for the syntax yields the following code snippet:

```bsh
$a = Get-Date
if (($a.Hour -ge 19) -Or ($a.Hour -lt 7)) { Write-Host "Off Hours" } else { Write-Host "On hours" }
```

Comment: Thank you BitTickler! Precise and concise. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified answer:

```
if ((get-date).Hour -in 7..19) {
   'Working Hours'
 } else { 
   'Off hours' 
 }
```